# Viewport is becoming slower the more I work on a scene

Tags: 3d-view, scene

Viewport is becoming slower and slower the more I use the scene regardless of the complexity of the scene.

So I have this problem ever since I started working with Blender, more than a year now, and I've notice that if I'm playing with a scene for a while the scene just becomes unusable for no logical reason whatsoever.
It becomes so slow that I can barely move basic objects even a default cube in wireframe mode...

It feels as if there is some sort of scene cache file that needs to be cleaned up ?

The workaround:

If I copy all of the objects in the scene and put them into a new scene the lag disappears and the viewport then becomes as responsive as new.

My question is why is this happening ? Is it just me ? Is there a way to fix or troubleshoot this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you [share](https://pasteall.org/blend/) you blend file in the post so we can see what is up with it? There could be a number of reasons.

Comment: I have used blender for a long time and I have never had this problem. You can show some hardware information and blender preference system settings to us.

Answer (score 0):

Usually It's due to a weak system or a small amount of ram, I always had this problem when using a weak laptop. The only thing that helped was restarting the blender (close it and reopen - should help)